# spiral meshgrid in matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, physics, matlab-figure

I'm trying to produce some computer generated holograms by using MATLAB. I used equally spaced mesh grid to initialize the spatial grid, and I got the following image

[image]

This pattern is sort of what I need except the center region. The fringe should be sharp but blurred. I think it might be the problem of the mesh grid. I tried generate a grid in polar coordinates and the map it into Cartesian coordinates by using MATLAB's `pol2cart` function. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as well. One may suggest that using fine grids. It doesn't work too. I think if I can generate a spiral mesh grid, perhaps the problem is solvable. In addition, the number of the spiral arms could, in general, be arbitrary, could anyone give me a hint on this?

I've attached the code (My final projects are not exactly the same, but it has a similar problem).

```
clc; clear all; close all;
%% initialization
tic
lambda = 1.55e-6;
k0 = 2*pi/lambda;
c0 = 3e8;
eta0 = 377;
scale = 0.25e-6;
NELEMENTS = 1600;
GoldenRatio = (1+sqrt(5))/2;
g = 2*pi*(1-1/GoldenRatio);

pntsrc = zeros(NELEMENTS, 3);
phisrc = zeros(NELEMENTS, 1);
for idxe = 1:NELEMENTS
  pntsrc(idxe, :) = scale*sqrt(idxe)*[cos(idxe*g), sin(idxe*g), 0];
  phisrc(idxe) = angle(-sin(idxe*g)+1i*cos(idxe*g));
end
phisrc = 3*phisrc/2; % 3 arms (topological charge ell=3)

%% post processing
sigma = 1;
polfilter = [0, 0, 1i*sigma; 0, 0, -1; -1i*sigma, 1, 0]; % cp filter

xboundl = -100e-6; xboundu = 100e-6;
yboundl = -100e-6; yboundu = 100e-6;
xf = linspace(xboundl, xboundu, 100);
yf = linspace(yboundl, yboundu, 100);
zf = -400e-6;
[pntobsx, pntobsy] = meshgrid(xf, yf);
% how to generate a right mesh grid such that we can generate a decent result?
pntobs = [pntobsx(:), pntobsy(:), zf*ones(size(pntobsx(:)))];
% arbitrary mesh may result in "wrong" results

NPNTOBS = size(pntobs, 1);
nxp = length(xf);
nyp = length(yf);

%% observation
Eobs = zeros(NPNTOBS, 3);

matlabpool open local 12
parfor nobs = 1:NPNTOBS
  rp = pntobs(nobs, :);
  Erad = [0; 0; 0];
  for idx = 1:NELEMENTS
    rs = pntsrc(idx, :);
    p = exp(sigma*1i*2*phisrc(idx))*[1 -sigma*1i 0]/2; % simplified here
    u = rp - rs;
    r = sqrt(u(1)^2+u(2)^2+u(3)^2); %norm(u);
    u = u/r; % unit vector
    ut = [u(2)*p(3)-u(3)*p(2),...
      u(3)*p(1)-u(1)*p(3), ...
      u(1)*p(2)-u(2)*p(1)]; % cross product: u cross p
    Erad = Erad + ... % u cross p cross u, do not use the built-in func
      c0*k0^2/4/pi*exp(1i*k0*r)/r*eta0*...
      [ut(2)*u(3)-ut(3)*u(2);...
      ut(3)*u(1)-ut(1)*u(3); ...
      ut(1)*u(2)-ut(2)*u(1)]; 
  end
  Eobs(nobs, :) = Erad; % filter neglected here
end
matlabpool close
Eobs = Eobs/max(max(sum(abs(Eobs), 2))); % normailized

%% source, gaussian beam
E0 = 1;
w0 = 80e-6;
theta = 0; % may be titled
RotateX = [1, 0, 0; ...
  0, cosd(theta), -sind(theta); ...
  0, sind(theta), cosd(theta)];

Esrc = zeros(NPNTOBS, 3);
for nobs = 1:NPNTOBS
  rp = RotateX*[pntobs(nobs, 1:2).'; 0];
  z = rp(3);
  r = sqrt(sum(abs(rp(1:2)).^2));
  zR = pi*w0^2/lambda;
  wz = w0*sqrt(1+z^2/zR^2);
  Rz = z^2+zR^2;
  zetaz = atan(z/zR);
  gaussian = E0*w0/wz*exp(-r^2/wz^2-1i*k0*z-1i*k0*0*r^2/Rz/2+1i*zetaz);% ...
  Esrc(nobs, :) = (polfilter*gaussian*[1; -1i; 0]).'/sqrt(2)/2;
end
Esrc = [Esrc(:, 2), Esrc(:, 3), Esrc(:, 1)];
Esrc = Esrc/max(max(sum(abs(Esrc), 2)));  % normailized
toc

%% visualization
fringe = Eobs + Esrc; % I'll have a different formula in my code
normEsrc = reshape(sum(abs(Esrc).^2, 2), [nyp nxp]);
normEobs = reshape(sum(abs(Eobs).^2, 2), [nyp nxp]);
normFringe = reshape(sum(abs(fringe).^2, 2), [nyp nxp]);

close all;
xf0 = linspace(xboundl, xboundu, 500);
yf0 = linspace(yboundl, yboundu, 500);
[xfi, yfi] = meshgrid(xf0, yf0);
data = interp2(xf, yf, normFringe, xfi, yfi);
figure; surf(xfi, yfi, data,'edgecolor','none');
% tri = delaunay(xfi, yfi); trisurf(tri, xfi, yfi, data, 'edgecolor','none');
xlim([xboundl, xboundu])
ylim([yboundl, yboundu])
% colorbar
view(0,90)
colormap(hot)
axis equal
axis off
title('fringe thereo. ', ...
  'fontsize', 18)
```

Comment: I'm not sure... I think you might already be the expert in arbitrarily armed spiral meshgrids. But let us know if you find the answer - the world needs more spirals like this.

Comment: I'm not able to generate a spiral meshgrid in an efficient way. And the figure herein is not accurate indeed.

Comment: show us your code so we see why this happens.

Comment: I've attached partial code.

Comment: It's hot colormap. If you apply another one, like even jet, you get much less blurriness. If you think it's not the case, you will probably have to change the function you are using.

Comment: I realized that. But what you suggest is not exactly what I need. As you said, if I apply a jet color map, I'll get much blurriness, indicating that the fringe is sharp in nature. (Actually it is.) The magnitude in the center region should be higher I think. If so, no matter what kind of color function we use, we can always get a nice fringe with less blurriness in the middle.

Comment: When I said "change the function" I meant not color function, but your spiral calculations. Yes, the center magnitude goes down and it's not as sharp as other edges. Better to see with `view` and `axis off` statements commented.

Comment: Alright, I got your point. Yes, I think changing the mesh grid may solve the problem. But I'm not very clear how?

Comment: Dude, I executed your code and it is AWESOME. What is the problem? when you mean sharp but blurred what do you exactly mean? Do  you have an image to show us what is the exact, or similar desired output? Sorry, I can't imagine what do you expect :S

Answer (score 4):

I didn't read your code because it is too long to do such a simple thing. I wrote mine and here is the result:

[image]

the code is

```
%spiral.m
function val = spiral(x,y)

  r = sqrt( x*x + y*y);
  a = atan2(y,x)*2+r;                  

  x = r*cos(a);
  y = r*sin(a);

  val = exp(-x*x*y*y);

   val = 1/(1+exp(-1000*(val)));   

endfunction


%show.m
n=300;
l = 7;
A = zeros(n);

for i=1:n
for j=1:n
    A(i,j) = spiral( 2*(i/n-0.5)*l,2*(j/n-0.5)*l);
end
 end


imshow(A) %don't know if imshow is in matlab. I used octave.
```

the key for the sharpnes is line

```
val = 1/(1+exp(-1000*(val)));
```

It is [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). The number 1000 defines how sharp your image will be. So lower it for more blurry image or higher it for sharper.

I hope this answers your question ;)

Edit: It is real fun to play with. Here is another spiral:

[image: spiral2]

```
function val = spiral(x,y)

   s= 0.5;

   r = sqrt( x*x + y*y);
   a = atan2(y,x)*2+r*r*r;                  

  x = r*cos(a);
  y = r*sin(a);

  val = 0;  
  if (abs(x)<s )
    val = s-abs(x);
    endif
 if(abs(y)<s)
    val =max(s-abs(y),val); 
    endif

   %val = 1/(1+exp(-1*(val)));

endfunction
```

Edit2: Fun, fun, fun! Here the arms do not get thinner.

[image: spiral3]

```
  function val = spiral(x,y)

   s= 0.1;

   r = sqrt( x*x + y*y);
   a = atan2(y,x)*2+r*r;                  % h

  x = r*cos(a);
  y = r*sin(a);

  val = 0;  
  s = s*exp(r);
  if (abs(x)<s )
    val = s-abs(x);
    endif
 if(abs(y)<s)
    val =max(s-abs(y),val); 
    endif
 val = val/s;   
 val = 1/(1+exp(-10*(val)));

 endfunction
```

Damn your question I really need to study for my exam, arghhh!

Edit3:

I vectorised the code and it runs much faster.

```
%spiral.m
  function val = spiral(x,y)   
   s= 2;

   r = sqrt( x.*x + y.*y);
   a = atan2(y,x)*8+exp(r);                  

  x = r.*cos(a);
  y = r.*sin(a);

  val = 0;  
  s = s.*exp(-0.1*r);
  val = r;
  val =  (abs(x)<s ).*(s-abs(x));
  val = val./s;

 % val = 1./(1.+exp(-1*(val)));  
 endfunction


%show.m

n=1000;
l = 3;
A = zeros(n);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-l:2*l/n:l);
A = spiral(X,Y);
imshow(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't post figures. But this might help. I wrote it for experiments with amplitude spatial modulators...

```
R=70;           % radius of curvature of fresnel lens (in pixel units)
A=0;             % oblique incidence by linear grating (1=oblique 0=collinear)
B=1;             % expanding by fresnel lens (1=yes 0=no)
L=7;            % topological charge
Lambda=30;       % linear grating fringe spacing (in pixels)
aspect=1/2;      % fraction of fringe period that is white/clear
xsize=1024;       % resolution (xres x yres number data pts calculated)
ysize=768;        % 

% define the X and Y ranges (defined to skip zero)
xvec = linspace(-xsize/2, xsize/2, xsize);     % list of x values
yvec = linspace(-ysize/2, ysize/2, ysize);     % list of y values

% define the meshes - matrices linear in one dimension
[xmesh, ymesh] = meshgrid(xvec, yvec);

% calculate the individual phase components
vortexPh = atan2(ymesh,xmesh);       % the vortex phase
linPh = -2*pi*ymesh;           % a phase of linear grating
radialPh = (xmesh.^2+ymesh.^2);     % a phase of defocus

% combine the phases with appropriate scales (phases are additive)
% the 'pi' at the end causes inversion of the pattern
Ph = L*vortexPh + A*linPh/Lambda + B*radialPh/R^2;

% transmittance function (the real part of exp(I*Ph))
T = cos(Ph);
% the binary version
binT = T > cos(pi*aspect);

% plot the pattern
% imagesc(binT)
imagesc(T)
colormap(gray)
```